# Android Studio: Display a message if the camera is covered

Tags: android

I am writing an Android-app that uses the camera. To make it user-friendly, I'd like to display a message when the picture is too dark or the user has his finger in the lens. Is there any possibility to get the camera-state and decide wether it is covered by something or the camera lens is free?

Answer (score 1):

In order to detect whether the camera is covered by some object or not you will have to use OpenCV library and perform the action accordingly after the object is detected. There is nothing inbuilt in android for the task you want to achieve.

[Link to OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Camera.PreviewCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) coupled with the Camera class to get a callback with a byte array, that byte array contain the image data of that frame.
Then you'll need some sort of algorithm/logic to determine whether or not it's "too dark". There is nothing built into Android that can help you determine that.